# unidentified space between header and body

Tags: html, css, web

I have been browsing about it but i cannot relate any answer, basically there is a white gap between Header and Body, see below:

[image]

I read somewhere that some elements have default margins or padding like the `<ul>` but i cannot really identified as i am just getting into web.

Here is how my items are positioned:

```
header{
background-color: white;
position:relative;
}

p.secondaryText {
color: darkgray;
}

.menu{
background-color: dodgerblue;
}

.logo{
position: relative;
width: 100%;
}

.logo-img{
position: relative;
margin: 10px 15px 15px 100px;
width: 120px;
height: 100px;
}

.social{
width: 100%;
height: 50px;
padding-left: 100px;
padding-right: 50px;
padding-bottom: 10px;
padding-top: 10px;
}

.division{
height: 2px;
width: 100%;
background-color: lightgray;
}

.img-container{
position: absolute;
opacity: 0.75;
filter: alpha(opacity=20);
width: 100%; /* or any custom size */
height: 100%; 
}

.body-container {
height: 600px;
width: 100%;
clear: both;
position: relative;
}

body{
margin: 0;
}


#frontText {
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
right: 0;
margin-bottom: 30px;
color: white;
font-size: 50px;
text-shadow: 2px 0 0 #000, -2px 0 0 #000, 0 2px 0 #000, 0 -2px 0 #000, 1px 1px #000, -1px -1px 0 #000, 1px -1px 0 #000, -1px 1px 0 #000;
background-color: transparent;
}

.main-body{
position: relative;
text-align: center;
}

.options-section{
text-align: center;
}

.services-box, .company-box, .contact-box{
position: relative;
width: 250px;
height: 200px;
margin-right: 60px;
background-color: dodgerblue;
display: inline-block;
}

footer{
background-color: black;
height: 200px;
}
```

and the menu:

```
ul {
padding: 0;
margin-left: 80px;
}


li {
display: inline;
}

li a{
font-weight: bold;
color: white;
font-size: 15px;
display: inline-block;
padding: 10px 15px;
}

li a:hover{
text-decoration: none;
}
```

I have tried the margins but doesn't have any impact.

**EDIT :**

you can download the [project](https://github.com/mastakillahBlitzar/TaniguchiWeb.git) on github if you wish to, is running on node js, just node server and listen in port 9000

> http://localhost:9000/index.html

.

Comment: can you add the relevant html?

Comment: If you had a live link it would be easier to figure out.  I would take a peek if I could

Comment: I am sorry I don't, I am running on a node.js local server

Comment: @Juanca Just guessing would be so hard..

Comment: Use developer tools to identify that space. Inspect your header and body properly and see what element is that white space in.

Comment: I did try developer tools, it seems header stops there  and body stars a bit further down is just a white space as i can see

Comment: I added github link maybe you can run in local server

Comment: @Juanca Not sure of the reason for this, but the solution is to add `margin-bottom:-10px` to the header element!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have said, there is default styles for many elements, one of them is the `UL`.

All you need to do, is to override it with `margin: 0`.

```css
header {
  background-color: white;
  position: relative;
}

p.secondaryText {
  color: darkgray;
}

.menu {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
}

.menu ul {
  margin: 0;
}

.logo {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.logo-img {
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px 15px 15px 100px;
  width: 120px;
  height: 100px;
}

.social {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  padding-left: 100px;
  padding-right: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.division {
  height: 2px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

.img-container {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0.75;
  filter: alpha(opacity=20);
  width: 100%;
  /* or any custom size */
  height: 100%;
}

.body-container {
  height: 600px;
  width: 100%;
  clear: both;
  position: relative;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

#frontText {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 50px;
  text-shadow: 2px 0 0 #000, -2px 0 0 #000, 0 2px 0 #000, 0 -2px 0 #000, 1px 1px #000, -1px -1px 0 #000, 1px -1px 0 #000, -1px 1px 0 #000;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.main-body {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.options-section {
  text-align: center;
}

.services-box,
.company-box,
.contact-box {
  position: relative;
  width: 250px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-right: 60px;
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  display: inline-block;
}

footer {
  background-color: black;
  height: 200px;
}

and the menu: ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin-left: 80px;
}

li {
  display: inline;
}

li a {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  font-size: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 15px;
}

li a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<header>

  <div class="social">

    <p class="secondaryText">It is a long established fact that</p>

  </div>

  <div class="division"></div>

  <div class="logo">
    <img class="logo-img" src="R/Metalplatelogo.jpg">

  </div>

  <div class="menu" id="myMenu">
    <nav>

      <ul>

        <li><a href="index.html">トップページ</a></li>
        <li><a href="business.html">事業内容</a></li>
        <li><a href="company.html">会社概要</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">お問い合わせ</a></li>
        <li><a href="">NEWS</a></li>

      </ul>

    </nav>

  </div>

</header>



<div class="body-container">
  <img class="img-container" src="http://via.placeholder.com/2000x2000">
  <div id="frontText">確かな技術と最新鋭の設備。<br> 半世紀に渡る信頼に支えられて<br> 私たちは、あらゆるニーズに取り組み続けています。</div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.6/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="controllersJS/controllerEvent.js"></script>

<div class="main-body">
  <p>有限会社谷口板金工業所は、屋根・外壁工事を専門とする会社です。</p>
  <h2>屋根・外壁のことならおまかせください。</h2><br>
  <p>住宅から工場やビル・神社仏閣などの大規模施設まで、あらゆる建築物に対応し工事いたします。<br>長年の実績と豊富な経験で培った技術、そして最新鋭の設備でお客様のあらゆるニーズにお応えします。</p>


</div>

<div class="options-section">

  <div class="services-box">

  </div>

  <div class="company-box">

  </div>

  <div class="contact-box">

  </div>


</div>

<div class="about-section">

</div>

<div class="news-section">

</div>

<div class="map">
  <iframe width="400" height="250" frameborder="0" style="border:0" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=AIzaSyB3Dg5WXMBa21xvPSgdEzx-Q9aX42xgwt4&#10;                &amp;q=Space+Needle,Seattle+WA" allowfullscreen="">
            </iframe>

</div>


<footer>
  This is the footer


</footer>
```

Comment: awesome and that was it, how can I know which elements are having a default margin or padding?

Comment: Chrome devtool’s “inspect element” will do the job

Answer (score 0):

Could you not just make the body margin: 0; & padding: 0;? & then set the margin and padding to each element if you want margin/padding?

```
body {
margin: 0; 
padding: 0; }
```

Comment: the <ul> was the element that was actually causing that problem , so .menu ul applied margin: 0; and walla!